# JavaScript - Wondering how can this be

Tags: javascript, html

So I am learning JavaScript right now and I am making this calculator. Started it like any other JavaScript. Make html file, put in all the html tags and so on, make the special `<script></script>` tags into which I will write the code. Now my solution involved a lot of variables and if statements and so on..

But then I wondered how others have done it and i Stumbled upon this:

```
<FORM NAME="Calc">
<TABLE BORDER=4>
<TR>
<TD>
<INPUT TYPE="text"   NAME="Input" Size="16">
<br>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="one"   VALUE="  1  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += '1'">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="two"   VALUE="  2  " OnCLick="Calc.Input.value += '2'">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="three" VALUE="  3  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += '3'">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="plus"  VALUE="  +  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += ' + '">
<br>
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="four"  VALUE="  4  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += '4'">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="five"  VALUE="  5  " OnCLick="Calc.Input.value += '5'">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="six"   VALUE="  6  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += '6'">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="minus" VALUE="  -  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += ' - '">
<br>
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="seven" VALUE="  7  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += '7'">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="eight" VALUE="  8  " OnCLick="Calc.Input.value += '8'">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="nine"  VALUE="  9  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += '9'">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="times" VALUE="  x  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += ' * '">
<br>
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="clear" VALUE="  c  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value = ''">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="zero"  VALUE="  0  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += '0'">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="DoIt"  VALUE="  =  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value = eval(Calc.Input.value)">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="div"   VALUE="  /  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += ' / '">
<br>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</FORM>
```

It's not indented really well but the point is that, it's javascript as I understand yes? And the person has not even used the script tags for it. Just putting the code randomly in a html file and bam it work. How can this be?

Comment: Look at the source for a `<script src` element that point to a file containing the script (there will be one if there is no script in the page itself)

Comment: This code is not positioned "randomly". It works because it's supposed to work like that.

Comment: It's not randomly inserted, it's in event handlers, but it's really, really bad practice and horrible code. Don't do it like this. Just pretend you never saw it. Maybe some eye-bleach would help?

Comment: @AlexK.: No - it works exactly as it is. No external scripts needed: http://jsfiddle.net/yz5Wc/

Comment: @Matt Burland - But why is it bad practice?

Comment: write into the input field `alert("foo")` and hit `=`. Basically the user can run random javascript code this way. Then you know, why it's bad practice.

Comment: @Veske: Seriously? Scattering code in your view is never a good idea and always becomes a massive pain to maintain. That's why it's bad practice. Separate out your logic and your view and it's much easier to maintain, update, test and debug. And to that the use of `eval` which means a user can run arbitrary code by just typing in the input box and this is a total nightmare.

Comment: see: http://24ways.org/2005/dont-be-eval/ for a simple explanation or: http://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Sullivan/BH_US_11_Sullivan_Server_Side_WP.pdf for a more detailed explanation about the vulnerability issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, this is horrible code. If you are learning Javascript, this is a great example of how *not* to do it.

It works because they've put Javascript code in the event handlers and even without specifying most (all) browsers will interpret that as Javascript. They can access the various inputs by exploiting that most browsers will automatically create a variable for any named controls.

And then for bonus points they use `eval` which is evil.

Seriously, this is really bad code. You'd see a lot of code like this in the early 90's. Just move on and learn Javascript properly. Start here: [JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)

Comment: I would not consider Crockfords Book as lecture for the bloody beginner. Also one has to admit, that it's a quite clever solution;)

Comment: I think *The Good Parts* is an excellent book for a JavaScript beginner, but not a programming beginner.

Comment: @Quentin: I think that's a very fair observation.

Answer (score 1):

Its acceptable to have the javascript in the OnClick attribute of the INPUTs HTML, you don't need a script block unless you have either standalone code call, block of code or are importing another JS file

Answer (score 1):

It's mostly HTML. It has `onclick` attributes which contain the body of a JavaScript function that is bound to the `click` event on the element.

Answer (score 1):

It's just how embeded javascript works. According to O'Reilly's Java Guide:

> Client-side JavaScript code is embedded within HTML documents in a
>   number of ways:
>
> Between a pair of  and  tags
>
> From an external file specified by the src attribute of a  tag
>
> In an event handler, specified as the value of an HTML attribute such
>   as onclick or onmouseover
>
> As the body of a URL that uses the special javascript: protocol

Answer (score 1):

When a button is clicked, it calls the `onClick` function. You can place a simple piece of Javascript inside that parameter to be called when the button is clicked.

The Javascript [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function evaluates a string as Javascript code. That is what the button named "DoIt" does. The rest of the buttons simply append the numbers and operators to the `Calc.Input.value` string. Clicking "=" evaluates the `Calc.Input.value` string.

`Calc.Input.value` is referring to the value of the element named `Input` inside the form named `Calc`.

Answer (score 1):

The `onclick` attribute (and other similar event handler attributes) is special, it's value is actually JavaScript - similarly to the value of the `style` attribute that is actually CSS.

For example `onclick="Calc.Input.value = ''"` would execute the JavaScript `Calc.Input.value = ''`. Due to automation by the browser, `Calc` references the Form element, then `Input` references the Input tag and `.value` is simply a property of Input.

That example you found looks very, very old and has poor coding style. I would stay away from it.